# How to maniplulate data in one array if conditions are met in another array?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

I have an array of numeric data, and I have another with the string headers of that data. these two arrays match in terms of what header goes with which column. I want to write an if statement that says for each column in the headers array, if the string value in column 1 for example equals 'header1', then take column 1 from the data array and multiply all values by 10 (or apply some function to the data in each cell). if it equals a different string do something else, and then move on to the next string in the header array and repeat the process.

Here is what I have so far. names is the array with 1 column and some string headers and Data is the new data file, while dataToRead is the original data array. there must be a betetr way to do this, I might have anwyhere from 1 to 20 formulas/headers so making a million if else statements seems wrong. 
Somewhere down the line I would like to have a repository of formulas that can be applied for each string case so that I can have it cycle through instead of having 20 if statements. is that possible?

This code seems to work just fine, but it cant be the best way to go about this.

```
for n=1:length(names)
if names{:,n}=='header1'
Data(:,n)=3*DataToRead(:,n+1); %I have a time stamp in column 1 i dont want to act upon
else
if names{:,n}=='header2'
Data(:,n)=4*DataToRead(:,n+1)
else
if names{:,n}=='header4'
Data(:,n)=0*DataToRead(:,n+1)
end 
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
headers = {'header1', 'header2', 'header4'};
for n = 1:length(names)
   headerstring = names{:,n};
   [temp, N] = max(strcmp(headerstring, headers));
   % // N now contains which in the list of 'headers', 'headerstring' matches.
   % // strcmp(string, stringcellarray) returns a vector of 0s and 1s ...
   % // ... corresponding to if string equals stringcellarray(i)
   Data(:, n) = myfunc(DataToRead(:,n+1), N);
end
```

And then in another file, you would have:

```
function val = myfunc(x, N)
    switch N
        case 1
             val = 3.0 * x;
        case 2
             val = 4.0 * x;
        case 3
             val = 0.0 * x;
        otherwise
             error('Case not found');
    end
end
```

Unless you can index every header with a number 'n' and associate every formula you need to write with 'n', you're unfortunately probably going to have to hand-code every formula.

It isn't clear what 'names' is, by the way. Is it a 1-D array of strings?  It seems like you have a cell for every character in 'names'.

Also, be careful 'if ... == ...' statement with strings. It returns a vector of true/false for each character and 'if' implicitly checks if all are true. Use 'strcmp' instead.

**EDIT:** Actually a much cleaner way than using the `max` function is to use the `find` function.
Use:

```
N = find(strcmp(headerstring, headers), 1);
```

The idea behind both the `max` and `find` statements is to find the index of the first non-zero element in the 0/1 vector returned by the `strcmp` function.

The `strcmp` function will return a vector of size `size(headers)`. It will have entries equal `1` in all locations where `headers` matched `headerstring`. The remaining entries would be zero.

**Caution:** For this particular code to work, headers must be a cell array (like a vector) and not a cell matrix (2 dimensions or more).

An explanation of the max statement:

```
[temp, N] = max(strcmp(headerstring, headers));
```

This function finds the index N such that headstring matches headers{N}. It is done as follows:

- The strcmp(headerstring, headers) returns a 0/1 vector corresponding to where `headerstring` matches `headers`.
- `max` with 1 return value then would obviously return `1`. But we want the *index* of that. So we use `max` with 2 outputs. The first, `temp`, is just `1`. The other output argument contains the `index` of that (see MATLAB's documentation on `max`)
- The `find` function does the same in one step. Use that.

Comment: names is a nx1 cell array of strings. where n is however many strings/formulas i have.

Comment: What sort of formulas do you have?

Comment: can you explain the temp,N line? matlab is saying N=3, or N=4 but it is only using the N =1 case on my data for all the columns regardless of that value. what does temp do?

Comment: done. in fact, i replaced it by a 'find' function which is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: I redid my post from the ground up to explain the details better.

This code will do what you need. Read on for an explanation.

```
nNames = length(names);
nHeaders = length(headers);
rpmNames = repmat(names',1,nHeaders);
rpmHeaders = repmat(headers,nNames,1);
I = cellfun( @isequal, rpmNames, rpmHeaders  );
[idx ~] = ind2sub( size(I), find(I) );
output = bsxfun(@times,Data,multipliers(idx));
```

---

This process would have 4 inputs:

1. a `1xn` cell array called `names` listing all `n` possible headers
2. a `1xn` numeric array called `multipliers` giving the `n` multiplication factors to go along with the possible header names
3. a `1xh` cell array called `headers` listing some combination of the headers in `names`, corresponding to the the `h` columns in the `Data` matrix
4. a `Dxh` matrix of numerical data called `Data`; the number of rows `D` is irrelevant

I'll use the following example inputs if you need something to copy:

```
names = {'h1';'h2';'h3';'h4'};
multipliers = [3 4 0 10]; 
headers = {'h1','h2','h1','h4','h1','h3','h1','h2'};
Data = [ 
      9     4     2     5     9     5     5    10
     10     6     1     1     7    10     6     0
      4     3     3     3     5     5     7     9
      1     6     3     8     6     5     4     9
      3     7     4     0     2     2     4     8 ];
```

---

Here is a walk-through of the code:

Start by getting the number of header types `nNames` and number of actual headers `nHeaders`

```
nNames = length(names);
nHeaders = length(headers);
```

We want to assign numbers to the entries in `headers` based on the index of the corresponding headers in `names`. First we use `repmat` on our cell arrays.

```
rpmNames = repmat(names',1,nHeaders)
rpmHeaders = repmat(headers,nNames,1)
```

This should print out the following:

```
rpmNames = 

    'h1'    'h1'    'h1'    'h1'    'h1'    'h1'    'h1'    'h1'
    'h2'    'h2'    'h2'    'h2'    'h2'    'h2'    'h2'    'h2'
    'h3'    'h3'    'h3'    'h3'    'h3'    'h3'    'h3'    'h3'
    'h4'    'h4'    'h4'    'h4'    'h4'    'h4'    'h4'    'h4'

rpmHeaders = 

    'h1'    'h2'    'h1'    'h4'    'h1'    'h3'    'h1'    'h2'
    'h1'    'h2'    'h1'    'h4'    'h1'    'h3'    'h1'    'h2'
    'h1'    'h2'    'h1'    'h4'    'h1'    'h3'    'h1'    'h2'
    'h1'    'h2'    'h1'    'h4'    'h1'    'h3'    'h1'    'h2'
```

Next we check where the `headers` correspond to our `names` using element-by-element `isequal()`. We can do this using `cellfun()`.

```
I = cellfun( @isequal, rpmNames, rpmHeaders  )
```

This prints out

```
I =

     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

You can see that, for any column, the row index of the `1`' tell us the numeric index of the header name in `names`. We can get the row indexes using `find` to locate the `1` entries, and get the rows using `ind2sub`

```
[idx ~] = ind2sub( size(I), find(I) )
```

Here are the numeric indexes.

```
idx =

     1     2     1     4     1     3     1     2
```

Since these are the indexes to of the headers in `names`, we can also use these indexes in `multipliers`, since the positions correspond to `names`. To see this, type `multipliers(idx)`

```
ans =

     3     4     3    10     3     0     3     4
```

The last step is just to apply these multipliers to the columns of `Data`. We can do this using `bsxfun`, which basically does `repmat` and then an element-by-element operator all at once. We'll use `@times` operator for multiplication.

```
output = bsxfun(@times,Data,multipliers(idx))
```

And this gives us our desired output.

```
27    16     6    50    27     0    15    40
30    24     3    10    21     0    18     0
12    12     9    30    15     0    21    36
 3    24     9    80    18     0    12    36
 9    28    12     0     6     0    12    32
```

Comment: That is mostly correct The way you have it written I would have 3 arrays, the first being your table with the multiplication factors (how can i make this formulas?), the second being just the headers row in your data array, and the third being the data array (sans headers) with a column on the far left for timestamps (numeric seconds counting up). So from what I can tell i either need to merge the second and third arrays to make a data with headers array then try your code, or rework something. is that a better explanation?  The result you have is exactly what i am looking to get.

Comment: @excelhelp I re-wrote my post so it more closely matches what you have. I hope it helps.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to respond. I am working through your post and have a question. I know i have multipliers as my case in the post, but what if i wanted to put formulas like ax^2+bx+c , where 'x' is tied to one of my names. how would i place this in the multipliers variable?

Comment: Unlike `@times`, the function you gave only takes one argument, so I'm not sure you would apply this to your `Data` matrix after you use it on the headers. Do you just want to muliply `Data` by the result of that function?

Comment: multiplication was just a stand in since I don't know what the formulas will be yet and thought it would simplify my question so i could understand it better early on. basically i want to have a list of equations mapped to the list of header possibilities and act upon those. Similar to how we have multiplication values mapped to them now.

Comment: I have described this incorrectly and am going to delete this post and make a new one I think. my statement on the columns from headers to names matching is incorrect i think. im going to think about this and either delete or post an update. sorry.

Comment: @excelhelp I think there is a way to accomplish what you want using [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). If the problem has changed, then it might be a good idea to make a new question rather than discuss things in the comments. I don't think this question should be deleted, though, since I don't have the work saved anywhere else and it will be nice to refer to later if your new problem is similar.